# docker-compose volume on windows (with windows based image)

Tags: windows, docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to share host data with container running from windows based image. I'm configuring it in docker-compose file this way: volumes: - /C/Users:/code:rw. I'me getting error like this: ERROR: for builder  Cannot create container for service builder: invalid volume specification: '/C/Users:/code:rw'. Can anybody help me with this issue? Thank you

Comment: What happens when you remove the `rw` flag ? I'm pretty sure ntfs file system doesn't support Unix `rwx` permissions.

Comment: There is still an issue after removing rw